# How can I extract a short part of characters from the string with Regular Expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
s = '''I wish I may, I wish I might
Have a dish of fish tonight.'''

import re
m = re.search('w.*m', s)
print(m.group())
```

and I got the result:

```
wish I may, I wish I m
```

If I want to get the result only the first half `wish I m`, how can I revise my code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions, `.` means a single character and `.*` means any number of characters (0 or more).

When you used `w.*m`, by default, python will look for the longest sub-string that starts with `w` and ends with `m`.
This is called *GREEDY MATCH*.

To find a smaller sub-string in a string that starts with `w` and ends with `m`, you have to search *NON GREEDILY*.

For this, instead of using `w.*m`, use `w.*?m` .
Because of the `?` operator, python matches the first sub-string that is given by the regular expression.

Technically, `?` Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. example : `ab?` will match either `a` or `ab`.
So, Here, `w.*?m` will match minimum number of characters after `w`(included) that ends with `m`(included).

```
>>> s = '''I wish I may, I wish I might
... Have a dish of fish tonight.'''
>>>
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('w.*m', s)    #GREEDY SEARCH
>>> print(m.group())
wish I may, I wish I m
>>> m = re.search('w.*?m', s)   #NON GREEDY SEARCH
>>> print(m.group())
wish I m
```

Read more about REGULAR EXPRESSIONS [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.*?` to [match non-greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

```
>>> s = '''I wish I may, I wish I might
... Have a dish of fish tonight.'''
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('w.*?m', s)
>>> m.group()
'wish I m'
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish here? Your regular expression means it will match any of the following

```
'w.*m' will match:
'well my cat is married' -> 'well my cat is m'
'willy wonka had a wonky moped' -> 'willy wonka had a wonky m'
```

You are pretty much saying it should match any phrase that starts with `w` and ends with `m`.

`wish i m` appears twice in the phrase as highlighted below

"I `wish I m`ay, I `wish I m`ight
Have a dish of fish tonight."

So if that's the phrase you are looking for, your result should be `wish I m`, `wish I m`. For that result you'd need this pattern - `w[\w\s]*m`.  So instead of a greedy `.*` you are limiting the matched characters to words `\w` and spaces `\s` which is all that is in `will I m`.

Again, it depends on what you are looking for.

```
In [1]: import re
In [4]: x = 'I wish I may, I wish I might Have a dish of fish tonight'
In [5]: re.findall(r'w[\w\s]*m', x)
Out[5]: ['wish I m', 'wish I m']
```